# Show custom 'value' in Angular Material select element with multiple attribute

Tags: angular, drop-down-menu, angular-material

I am trying to create an angular MatSelect input with the multiple option like so:

```
<mat-select
  [formControl]="selectedValues"
  multiple
  (selectionChange)="updateSelectionLabel()"
>
  <mat-option *ngFor="let item of items" [value]="item" >
    {{ item }}
  </mat-option>
</mat-select>
```

When multiple items are selected, a list of the selected items is displayed in the UI:

```
item 1, item 2, it...
```

All of the items in my list have similar names, so I would rather show a string that says:

```
XX items selected
```

Is there a way to do this with Material Angular? As far as I can tell, you need to set `MatSelect.triggerValue`, but this appears to be a ready only property.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I missed an example of how to do this in the [docs](https://material.angular.io/components/select/examples). Here is a live demo of the example given:

https://stackblitz.com/angular/ovarbapvvdd?file=app%2Fselect-custom-trigger-example.ts